# How to make Tkinter & pygame work together?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pygame

The background of my game is an image the only problem is that two windows appear, I only want one. Two windows appear, one is small and with the image and the other is large but with nothing in it. What can I do to make both work together? Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as Tk

black = ("#000000")
white = ("#FFFFFF")
green = ("#00CD00")
yellow = ("#FFFF00")

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,720))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello Universe")

root = Tk.Tk()
background_image=Tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/jar/python/background_image.gif")
background_label = Tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
root.mainloop()

quit = False
while not quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit = True
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but mainloop isn't a variable, it's a function, try `top.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't need Tkinter you can just do this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
size = [1024, 720]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello Universe")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_image = pygame.image.load("background_image.gif").convert()

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


        screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```